# Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)--Clang

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int mm;
int dd;
int yy;
int deez;
int thawy;
char divine;
int yearcode(int yy){
int a=(yy/4)+yy;
int b=a%7;
return b;}
int monthcode(int mm){
    if(mm==1||mm==10){
        deez=0;
    } if(mm==2||mm==3){
        deez = 3;
    }if(mm==4||mm==7){
        deez=6;
    } if(mm==5){
        deez=1;
    }if(mm==6){
        deez=4;
    } if(mm==8){
        deez=2;
    } if(mm==9||mm==12) {
        deez = 5;
    }return deez;}
    int main() {
  printf("Please enter your date in the form mm/dd/yy\nEx. 03/26/19\n:");
  scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mm,&dd,&yy);
if(mm==1||mm==2){
thawy=(yearcode(yy)+monthcode(mm)+6+dd+-1)%7;
}else{
    thawy=(yearcode(yy)+monthcode(mm)+6+dd)%7;
}
if(thawy==0){
     divine="Sunday";
}if(thawy==1){
     divine="Monday";
}if(thawy==2){
   divine="Tuesday";
}if(thawy==3){
     divine="Wednesday";
}
if(thawy==4){
     divine="Thursday";
}if(thawy==5){
   divine="Friday";
}else{
    divine="Saturday";
}

printf("%d/%d/%d,is on a %s",mm,dd,yy,divine);
  return 0;
}
```

This block of code would allow the user to input data, and the output would be what day of the week the date is on. I'm fairly new to C, just been learning for about 4 days so I'm not sure how to fix this error. When the code is changed to output int thawy, the result is correct, however, printing the string 'divine' gives an error.

The string 'divine' is the cause of the error. Any Solutions? I'm pretty sure the error is caused by an issue with memory. Not too sure how to fix this, already tried the malloc function, might've used it wrong.

Comment: *not sure how to fix this error*. One of the first steps is to narrow down the root cause. And the way to do that is with basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and as a minimum get the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. Then examine the variables, especially pointers and buffer accesses, to see if anything looks wrong.

Comment: Crank up those compiler warnings and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/qKWWG8Mxh

Comment: Another important thing you can do is to format your code consistently. It may seem trivial but is very important - can't debug the code well if it can't be easily read. Make sure there are spaces between functions and indentation is consistently applied

Answer (score 1):

The variable "divine" is just a single character.  You cannot assign a string to it nor can your use the "%s" to display it.  Change it to a "char const *" vice a "char". A "char *" can point to a string and the "const" tells the compiler that the content cannot change.

Alternatively, you can use "char divine[10]" (9 for the longest string and 1 for the NUL character at the end) and use the strcpy function to copy the string.